Releasing and locking mouse events between multiple widgets
Straight to the point
I have multiple QLabel widgets inside QVBoxLayout.
When I press left mouse button and start dragging (I don't actually drag any widgets, I only move the mouse cursor while left mouse button is being pressed), one of the QLabels receives the mousePressEvent, and all subsequent mouseMoveEvents are sent to that QLabel which received the mousePressEvent, even when the mouse cursor has moved outside of the bounding box of this QLabel.
This does not work for me. I want the original QLabel which first received the mousePressEvent to stop receiving mouse events if the event occurred outside of the QLabel's bounding box. If it happens, I want the other QLabel (to where the cursor has moved)  to start handling the mouse events.
Setting mouse tracking to true did not help, "locking" still happens.
Any suggestions? Thanks <3

Some background
What I am actually implementing is text selection mechanism for my document viewer application.
Pixmaps are obtained from pages of a document and set as QLabels' pixmaps.
When a mousePressEvent occurs selection starts and continues on the following onMouseMove events. But when I want to select text from multiple pages and I move the mouse cursor to another QLabel, events are still being sent to that original QLabel. This is the issue. I have perfectly functioning selection mechanism for a single page. The issue arose just now when I realized that mouse events work this way in Qt.

UPD
I've recorded a short 1 minute video describing the problem - https://youtu.be/m00dV4s1Am8

You are going to have a difficult time because the behavior you are seeing is what people expect. When the user presses the mouse over a button widget (or other like widget), he or she is explicitly handing all following mouse events to that widget until mouse button release. This is basic UX. But it sounds like you are masquerading a button widget as a different kind of control. Could you provide more detail on what it is that you are trying to accomplish visually?

If you need the mouse events to be handled by a higher authority (i.e. the widget that owns the QLabel objects), one approach would be to make your QLabel subclass aware of this. Instead of handling mouse events directly, make it respond to them by emitting signals. Those are connected to slots on the owning widget, which can then choreograph the mouse logic for the document as a whole.

Another approach could be to use event filtering and therefore tracking down when the mouse press happens (keeping a reference to the object and the mouse position relative to that object) and manage any mouse movement until the button is released. Still, as noted above, a "higher authority" must be used: since the selection may span between more than one object, you cannot let that object manage it exclusively. This means that the above event filter and management must be installed on the "selection manager" (which is also probably the "document manager").

To be fair, doing what you tried is not impossible. But since, as said, an accepted mouse press will make the object the mouse grabber, that would mean that you'd need to implement a further mechanism to query other "siblings" or possibly trying to post a remapped event to them: unnecessary complications that would be even more prone to bugs if you're not careful about the implementation, which could become ugly and difficult to maintain or debug. Consider the proper object hierarchy: the real context of any selection is not its labels, so it must be managed at the parent/document level.

@Dúthomhas added link to the video showing what I am talking about. I agree, this is the expected behavior and it totally makes sense to me, I am not saying it's Qt's flaws.

@musicamante Using the parent of all QLabels was my first thought, however, I found it to be very inefficient since in this case, I will have to iterate through all widgets (QLabels) in the layout and resolve relative coordinates between the widgets to determine to which QLabel cursor has moved. But it is still an option.

@paddy my previous response is related to your comment

@VladPonomarev With all due respect, I have to disagree, as that's not "an option": it probably is the option. Dealing with complex object structures will almost always increase complexity and computational efficiency. If the implementation is done appropriately, it can amend some of the efficiency issues. For instance, you do not have to always iterate through all widgets: if you don't consider "drag selections" (selections that may scroll the contents), it's quite enough to know relative geometries of the widgets, then you just need to check if the position is within their rect.

@VladPonomarev regarding "I will have to iterate through all widgets..." -- why? You already get mouse events, and the window system is already more intelligent than just linearly searching everything. So if your widget emits a signal because the mouse moved over it, the owner already knows whether some kind of drag (or whatever) is in progress, thus whether to do anything about it. If you don't want to spam signals, you can use the mouse enter/leave events instead.

@VladPonomarev You have a relatively complex object structure, aiming for absolute efficiency is a chimera. You have to balance the efficiency of possible CPU computation and code implementation. The first objective is to find a proper way that conceptually and logically makes sense, respects the object hierarchy, and allows readable code that can be debugged appropriately. From that point, then, you can eventually do further optimizations if you find that the implementation is not efficient enough and those optimizations don't break anything.

Ah, nice video. Yes, the only way to solve it is to have a toplevel, invisible widget that moderates between your user and the displayed widgets — effectively intercepting mouse interactions and selectively mediating them with the appropriate object below. It has been some time since I’ve played with Qt, so I have no immediate suggestion on how this is best accomplished, but Qt’s slot and signal system is very complete, and IIRC has a mechanism whereby this can be accomplished.

I've achieved what I needed by following steps:

Widget (QLabel with pdf page in my case) receives a mousePressEvent and handles subsequent mouseMoveEvents
It accepts a mouseMoveEvent only in case if it occurred inside the bounding box of the widget.
If it occurred outside of widget's bounding box, it ignores it and the event is being sent to the parent widget, which holds the rest of the widgets (PagesContainer in my case is the parent, it hold all the QLabels with pdf pages).
The parent widget then resolves relative coordinates by using mapFromGlobal to get coordinates relative to the his coordinate system.
Then it tries to find a widget in its layout at specified coordinates by using childAt.
If a widget was found, it creates a new mouseMoveEvent with all parameters copied from the original mouseMoveEvent except the coordinates - they are being converted one more time, but to the found widget's coordinate system this time, and posts this event.

Here is the video demonstrating the solution: https://youtu.be/zHebZRYnF5Y?si=1zKBQs7JuEd2sjpp
Note: All mouseMoveEvents which occur outside of the very first (which captured the mousePressEvent) widget's bounding box  will still be forwarded through it's mouseMoveEvent handler. And every time it will ignore it, and every time the parent will have to do its job. What I don't like is that on every such event it will have to go through multiple widgets' event handlers, as well as the need to create a new event and post it to the found widget. This solution is not ideal, but it does it's job well.

Glad you got it working!
